# Call javascript function with php echo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I added a search box for a dropdown menu, that is solved by a javascript function.
Because i display the form and boxes with php ,i have problem to call the javascript function "searchSel():

```
 echo "<input type=\"text\" id=\"realtxt\" onkeyup="searchSel()"><s";
```

> Error: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'**

`onkeyup=". searchSel() ."`    does not work

Any ideas?

Comment: escape your quotes. `onkeyup=\"searchSel()\"`.

Comment: If you're trying to actually call a JavaScript function `searchSel()` from within PHP (e.g. have the output from `searchSel()` in the `onkeyup` event) ... you can't. PHP operates on the server and JS on the client. If `searchSel()` is actually PHP function you'll need `onkeyup=\"" . searchSel() . "\"" ... ` (quoted quotes)

Comment: ^ otherwise, what everyone else has written about escaping the quotes holds true (curse you 5 minute limit on editing comments)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Escape quotes

```
echo "<input type=\"text\" id=\"realtxt\" onkeyup=\"searchSel()\">
                                                  ^            ^
```

you forgot to escape `onkeyup="searchSel()"`

---

Better use single Quotes outside

```
echo '<input type="text" id="realtxt" onkeyup="searchSel()">'
     ^                                                      ^
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'd advocate using string literals on output (e.g. echo) since it'll all fall over the first time you do something like `echo '<p>{$sSomeOutput}</p>'` - granted, in this case is doesn't matter - but generally I'd stick to "normal" strings for output *shrugs*

Comment: ty. But with escaping the function is not callable. The Debuger says then: searchSel() is not defined. But the function is already included..

Comment: @mostworld77 In JavaScript?

Comment: @mostworld77 define your `searchSel()` function at the end after this element i added. Add function at the bottom of page.

Comment: `searchSel` doesn't need to be defined at the bottom of the page. Even more, there's a slight chance that it is called before it is defined. That's also why it's better to use progressive enhancement and bind the event handler in JavaScript, instead of in an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 echo "<input type=\"text\" id=\"realtxt\" onkeyup=\"searchSel()\">
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the string in single quotes, to avoid having to escape the double quotes:

```
echo '<input type="text" id="realtxt" onkeyup="searchSel()"><s';
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to escape searchSel()

```
echo "<input type=\"text\" id=\"realtxt\" onkeyup=\"searchSel()\">
```